# Material UI v1 with Redux - How to export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, material-ui

I am trying to make use of [Material-UI v1](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/) with stajuan's Redux-Saga Login template shown [here](https://github.com/sotojuan/saga-login-flow/blob/master/app/components/Login.js). So, I want to merge the `export default` thing of those two, in other words **combine two functions** for exporting the default class:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withStyles, createStyleSheet } from 'material-ui/styles';

// Redux
function select (state) {
    return {
    data: state
    }
}

// Material UI v1
const styleSheet = createStyleSheet(theme => ({
    // ...
}));

// Class to be exported
class Login extends Component {
    // ...
    render () {
        // ...
    }

}

// H O W   T O   M E R G E   T H O S E ? ? ?
// export default connect(select)(Login);
// export default withStyles(styleSheet)(Login);
```

The last two commented-out lines of the code above are the statements to be combined in my case.

Comment: See my answer on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704681/react-material-ui-export-multiple-higher-order-components

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to install `npm install recompose` or `yarn add recompose`

and on your export section

```
export default compose(
    withStyles(styles, {
        name: 'App',
    }),
    connect(),
)(AppFrame);
```

or you can do:

`export default withStyles(styles)(connect(select)(Cart));`

Answer (score 4):

You will be able to access with the key

```
this.props.domain
```

Add below line to export your class

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { domain : 'yourdomain.com'
    }
}
export default withStyles(styles)(connect(mapStateToProps)(Login));
```