# React Material UI - Export multiple higher order components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

I'm stuck on exporting material-ui styles with redux connector. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({});

const reduxConnector = connect(mapStateToProps, null);
const styles = theme => {
    console.log(theme);
    return ({
        paper: {
            top: '80px',
            boxShadow: theme.shadows[9]
        },
    });
};

class Cart extends Component {

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <Drawer
                open
                docked
                anchor="right"
                classes={{ paper: classes.paper }}
            >
                <p style={{ width: 250 }}>cart</p>

            </Drawer>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles, {name: 'Cart'})(Cart);
export default reduxConnector(Cart); // I want to add this
```

I've tried:

```
export default reduxConnector(withStyles(styles))(Cart); // return Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

export default withStyles(styles, {name: 'Cart'})(reduxConnector(Cart)); // return Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Cart)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Cart)".
```

Any solution?

Comment: Maybe it is time to pull out Drawer into a presentational component, and pass “open” and “docked” as props to it? That way you can keep your connected component away from having to deal with styles... On the other hand it can be annoying to write wrappers like that every time you use a material-ui components.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

install `npm install recompose` or `yarn add recompose`

and on your export section

```
export default compose(
    withStyles(styles, {
        name: 'App',
    }),
    connect(),
)(AppFrame);
```

and I forgot to export my store.

Answer (score 71):

Just try this

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles)(App));
```

Where App is your component. 
It works fine for me.

Comment: Excellent! For a simple setup using two functions connected to component. For more than two it's better `recompose`.

Comment: Just incase someone doesn't know what mapDispatchToProps means (like myself) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419237/what-is-mapdispatchtoprops

Comment: Yes, yes and yes!

Answer (score 35):

Take a look at how it's being handled in the material-ui docs site, specifically in the [AppFrame](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/4f75ae3dc80a6051aa9c59b91d2a5b96e90b5582/docs/src/modules/components/AppFrame.js) component:

```
export default compose(
  withStyles(styles, {
    name: 'AppFrame',
  }),
  withWidth(),
  connect(),
)(AppFrame);
```

They're using [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) to do this.

So in your case, it would be:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const styles = theme => {
  console.log(theme);
  return {
    paper: {
      top: '80px',
      boxShadow: theme.shadows[9],
    },
  };
};

const Cart = ({ classes }) =>
  <Drawer open docked anchor="right" classes={{ paper: classes.paper }}>
    <p style={{ width: 250 }}>cart</p>
  </Drawer>;

const mapStateToProps = state => ({});

export default compose(
  withStyles(styles, { name: 'Cart' }),
  connect(mapStateToProps, null)
)(Cart);
```

Comment: The AppFrame component link is returning a 404. @kengregory can you update the answer to include a successful link?

Comment: @robertjewell done.  Linked a version from a specific commit so that it remains valid.

Answer (score 13):

Without `recompose` or `compose`:

```
Cart = withStyles(styles, {name: 'Cart'})(Cart);
export default reduxConnector(Cart);
```

Comment: what is reduxConnector?

Comment: Look at the OP question

Answer (score 2):

This works perfect for me

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)((withStyles(styles)(ComponentNameToExport)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this below. As both withStyles and connect were higher order components

```
export default withStyles(styles, {name: 'Cart'})(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps), Cart);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Complete Component

```
    import React from "react";
    import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import ExpansionPanel from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanel";
    import ExpansionPanelSummary from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelSummary";
    import ExpansionPanelDetails from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelDetails";
    import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
    import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
    import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import { fetchPosts } from "../../store/actions/postActions";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";

    const useStyles = theme => ({
        root: {
            marginLeft: 250,
            marginRight: 10
        },
        heading: {
            fontSize: "1rem",
            fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
        }
    });

    class SimpleExpansionPanel extends React.Component {
        UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
            this.props.fetchPosts();
        }

        UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            if (nextProps.newPost) {
                this.props.postsa.unshift(nextProps.newPost);
            }
        }

        render() {
            const { classes } = this.props;
            const postItem = this.props.postsa.map(post => (
                <ExpansionPanel key={post.id}>
                    <ExpansionPanelSummary
                        expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                        aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                        id="panel1a-header">
                        <Typography className={classes.heading}>{post.title}</Typography>
                    </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                    <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                        <Typography>{post.body}</Typography>
                    </ExpansionPanelDetails>
                </ExpansionPanel>
            ));
            return <div className={classes.root}>{postItem}</div>;
        }
    }

    SimpleExpansionPanel.propTypes = {
        fetchPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        postsa: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        newPost: PropTypes.object
    };

    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        postsa: state.postss.items,
        newPost: state.postss.item
    });

    export default connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        { fetchPosts }
    )(withStyles(useStyles)(SimpleExpansionPanel));
```