# Rendering Component with custom styles with Material UI V1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

I am doing something fundamentally wrong leveraging Redux and Material UI V1, and I am looking for help. I have not been able to successfully style the width of my `Card` component at 75 pixels.

How are we suppose to pass custom styles to our components leveraging `withStyles` and `connect`? I have been following an example [here](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/paper/) in Material UI's docs on the `Paper` component but have not been able to style my UI successfully. Below are code snippets of my presentational and container component:

Container:

```
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';

import Home from '../components/Home';
import * as homeActions from '../modules/home';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: theme.mixins.gutters({
    width: 75,
  }),
});

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps = {}) => {
  return {
    props: {
      classes: styles,
      welcomeMessage: state.home.message || ''
    }
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps = {}) => {
  dispatch(homeActions.loadPage());

  return {
  };
};

export default compose(
  withStyles(styles),
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(Home)
```

Presentational:

```
import Card, { CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia } from 'material-ui/Card';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';

import photo from './party.png';

const Component = ({props}) => {
  return (
        <div>
      <Card classes={{
        root: props.classes.card
      }}>
        This is Paper
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

Component.propTypes = {
  props: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Component;
```

EDIT:

I have also leveraged this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704681/react-material-ui-export-multiple-higher-order-components) to see how the Redux and Material UI API for styling have been combined.

Also, I did not explicit state this but according to Material UI, all `Paper` props are valid for `Card` props in case you were wondering why I cited `Paper` documentation.

I also replaced code snippets where previously there were directly links to my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is acceptable for your *presentational component* to express its own style.

Export your presentational component using `withStyles`:

```js
import Card from 'material-ui/Card';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: theme.mixins.gutters({
    width: 75,
  }),
});

const Component = ({ classes }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Card className={classes.root}>This is Paper</Card>
    </div>
  );
};

Component.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.shape({
    root: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Component);
```

Then, in your container, you simply connect the presentational component's default export:

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. It lead me to the solution but it is not THE solution. I am going to provide my solution below.

Comment: uh, how is it not the solution?  You did exactly what I said to do.  You're using withStyles in the presentational component and you're no longer using it in the container.

Comment: Hey Ken, I greatly appreciate your answer. It definitely lead me to the solution. I'm happy to mark your answer as the solution. For the record, I had to do a bit more than just use withStyles in the presentational component. I also wanted to use props from my container. I'll delete my answer seeing as that it has been down voted and probably redundant.