# How to add react-i18next If I had already wrapped?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, i18next

I am following this:

https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-react-app-with-react-i18next

But, as you can see, I have to do this:

**export default translate()(App);**

But I am already using this in my component:

**export default withRouter(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles)(SignIn)));**

What Can I do in this case?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704681/react-material-ui-export-multiple-higher-order-components) answer, which answers this exact problem.

Long story short, it should be possible to just further wrap the [Higher Order Components (HOC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) like this:

```
export default withRouter(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles)(translate()(SignIn))));
```

or use [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) like in the answer linked above.

Comment: Gracias... estoy usando React con TypeScript. Y ahora estoy obteniendo este error:

Comment: TypeError: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference
getI18nTranslate
D:/jds3.0_cloud_web_app/node_modules/react-i18next/dist/es/I18n.js:138
  135 | }, {
  136 |   key: 'getI18nTranslate',
  137 |   value: function getI18nTranslate() {
> 138 |     return this.i18n.getFixedT(null, this.options.nsMode === 'fallback' ? this.namespaces : this.namespaces[0]);
  139 |   }
  140 | }, {
  141 |   key: 'render',

Comment: The translate function takes a string argument with the namespace of the translations and falls back to the default namespace defined in the i18next provider if you leave the argument empty. Please check out the [documentation](https://react.i18next.com/components/overview) and a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/8n252n822)