# how to integrate stylesheet and actions in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Newproject)
export default connect(null, { Newproject })(Newproject)
```

How do I integrate this two in same file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Material UI - Export multiple higher order components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704681/react-material-ui-export-multiple-higher-order-components)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this.

```
export default connect(null, { Newproject })(withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Newproject));
```